# What security controls exist such that user processes can't assign themselves highest priority?

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

I'm learning about the Linux process scheduler and have been reading through the pthread_setsched function: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

One thing that had surprised me is that threads are allowed to modify their own priority / class. I can see how this makes sense for configuring certain multi-thread applications (e.g. producers and consumers), however, it seems like a system stability risk that any process can just request to set its own priority. What's stopping my helloworld.out from requesting SCHED_FIFO at the highest priority? This could completely lock up the system.

So what mechanisms are in place to prevent a process from have full reign of the scheduler? It seems like a system error EPERM can be set, however, where is this configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel enforces this. The rules are detailed in [the “Privileges and resource limits” section of `man 7 sched`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html); in summary:

- `SCHED_DEADLINE` policies can only be modified by privileged threads (with `CAP_SYS_NICE`);
- real-time threads with `RLIMIT_RTPRIO` set to 0 can only lower their priorities or switch to a non-real-time policy;
- threads with non-zero `RLIMIT_RTPRIO` are bound to that limit, unless their priority has been set higher (by a privileged thread).

Threads with `CAP_SYS_NICE` can do whatever they want, but anything else is strictly controlled.

Comment: Adding that on pam-enabled system, one can enforce limits in /etc/security/limits.conf or any *.conf under the /etc/security/limits.d directory.